# Best way to run JUnit integration tests in production

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, production-environment

I am a Java developer, not a QA engineer, so my question may seem trivial to some.

How do I run my integration tests post-deployment? In normal build and deployment process, all JUnit tests are executed prior to deployment. After deployment is done, testing (as I understand) should be done using other (black box) methods. But what if I want to periodically check my application using my nice suite of integration tests?

What would be a proper way to run IT tests against an existing deployment (including production)?

Comment: Just curious, why? If you're not making changes to your code, surely your code integrates correctly making these tests irrelevant. If it doesn't work, it will be a matter of the input being sent to the system, which is why black box tests matter

Comment: If the code passes integration (not unit!) test once, it does not mean it will pass it twice. I want to make sure that the application runs correctly in real life based on realtime database data (which I won't be mocking).

Comment: There are far too many ways to do that; so your question is A) too broad and then B) asking for *opinions* ... thus really not suited here. SO is **not** a place to *discus* best practices.

Answer (score 3):

Many companies have two environments: production and UAT.  The production environment is the live production site.  UAT has the same build as production but can be used for testing, trying things out, and comparing if production has a problem.

Should you want to run JUnit tests on production (and like cjds i don't understand why you would), then UAT is the place to do it.

Comment: Thank you, testing in UAT environment is really a better practice. But still, how can I run IT tests against an already deployed artifact? Our UAT environment is not a build machine, I don't want to run javac or Maven there.